# SNMP equivalent for show ip route?

Tags: snmp

I'm new to SNMP.  Is there an equivalent in SNMP to "show ip route" on a Cisco 10K router?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[RFC1213-MIB](http://www.oidview.com/mibs/0/RFC1213-MIB.html) has an `ipRouteTable` tree containing the IP routing table:

```
[draytm01@mgt03 ~]$ snmpwalk -v 1 192.168.212.45 .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteDest.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteDest.192.168.212.0 = IpAddress: 192.168.212.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: 4
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteIfIndex.192.168.212.0 = INTEGER: 4
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMetric1.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: 1
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMetric1.192.168.212.0 = INTEGER: 0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteNextHop.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 192.168.212.1
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteNextHop.192.168.212.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteType.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: indirect(4)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteType.192.168.212.0 = INTEGER: direct(3)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteProto.0.0.0.0 = INTEGER: local(2)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteProto.192.168.212.0 = INTEGER: local(2)
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMask.0.0.0.0 = IpAddress: 0.0.0.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteMask.192.168.212.0 = IpAddress: 255.255.255.0
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteInfo.0.0.0.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
RFC1213-MIB::ipRouteInfo.192.168.212.0 = OID: SNMPv2-SMI::zeroDotZero
```

This is actually from a Linux box but I'd hope Cisco implemented RFC1213-MIB; I can't remember and I don't have any routers to hand.

Comment: Thank you.  Just what I needed.
I also discovered this great Cisco SNMP Object Navigator:
http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en

Answer (score 1):

While not Cisco specific, you can use:
   .1.3.6.1.2.1.4.21
which corresponds to
   .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.ip.ipRouteTable
from the RFC1213.mib  (check mibdepot.com for a copy).

If you want to search for a cisco specific MIB you might try:
http://www.mibdepot.com/cgi-bin/vendor_index.cgi?r=cisco

A good resource for SNMP education is www.wtcs.org/snmp4tpc/

Answer (score 1):

The answer above about RFC1213 MIB is often sufficient, but on some routers, you may need to or prefer to use inetCidrRouteTable, which is a little more detailed, and uses CIDR notation instead of transmitting the entire mask for every entry, and supports ipv4 and ipv6. see IP-FORWARD-MIB.txt installed with net-snmp for more information. I've seen at least one implementation that skipped RFC1213 MIB entirely ("No Such Object available on this agent at this OID") in favor of this other MIB.

```
snmptable [options] -c community hostname inetCidrRouteTable
```

This table would be quite large on many routers, so don't expect that to work quickly, or necessarily at all.

There is also ipCidrRouteTable, an older (v4 only) version of same thing.