# SNMP's command to determine is device router or host

Tags: snmp

How can be detect is device router or host by using snmp. I tried to use google. But nothing found.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to determine device type by polling sysObjectID ([1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.2.1.1.2)) - this should give you information about the vendor and device type (see e.g. [CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB](ftp://ftp.cisco.com/pub/mibs/oid/CISCO-PRODUCTS-MIB.oid) for the list of Cisco routers sysOIDs).

The other option is RFC-1213 sysServices which can indicate the routing capability of the device.

The following SF question has some details about routing table, which can serve as additional source of information [SNMP equivalent for show ip route?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41842/snmp-equivalent-for-show-ip-route).