# SNMP equivalent for "show ip route profile"

Tags: snmp

Is there an SNMP equalivalent implementation for the command "show ip route profile"?
How can I obtain the equivalent OIDs?

Appreciate your help.
Thanks.

Comment: What does "show ip route profile" do and on which device?

Answer (score 0):

First hit on google for "show ip route profile snmp oid" is [SNMP equivalent for show ip route?](https://serverfault.com/questions/41842/snmp-equivalent-for-show-ip-route)